# Shutdown so fast on iMac

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, macintosh

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on iMac 27 in dual boot with OSX via rEFInd.

It works nice but when I click to shutdown the Ubuntu it is so quickly and the screen becomes black in 1 or 2 seconds.

So I can not read any messages during the process (for example, on my laptop Sony I can read some process being killed).

My question: is the shutdown being normal or some forced process could corrupt something?

Does anybody have the same fast shutdown?

Comment: Dont complain that you're computer is too good.

Comment: @DisplayName, do you mean: the computer is good enough so shutdown is too fast?! Ow! It is too fast like when the power down.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps check `/var/log/messages` ?